# Represent Kmeans's cluster in graphics

Tags: r, k-means

I'm clustering `snsdata.csv` by kmeans algorithm into 5 clusters and I want to represent the clusters in some graphic for the better view. This is the code from *Machine Learning with R, 2nd Edition*:

```
teens <- read.csv("snsdata.csv")

# handle gender's NA values
teens$female <- ifelse(teens$gender == "F" & !is.na(teens$gender), 1, 0)
teens$no_gender <- ifelse(is.na(teens$gender), 1, 0)

# handle age's NA values
teens$age <- ifelse(teens$age >= 13 & teens$age <= 20, teens$age, NA)
ave_age <- ave(teens$age, teens$gradyear, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
teens$age <- ifelse(is.na(teens$age), ave_age, teens$age)

# now is clustering
interests <- teens[5:40]
interests_z <- as.data.frame(lapply(interests, scale))
teen_clusters <- kmeans(interests_z, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the data you are referring to, but as long as points are in less than 4D, you can show your clusters graphically by simply showing each cluster in different color/point etc.

When you have more than 3 dimensional space, you can use a dimensionality-reduction method to reduce the space to less than 4D and then use it *just* for representation(while using all the dimensions when clustering).

Comment: my data is the "snsdata.csv" and thanks for gave me some keywords